# Getting bigint id fields when using Django and Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Djangos ORM uses a integer datatype for the automatically created ID column, but I need them to be bigint (using postgres backend).  Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

### Django 1.10

Use the newly added [BigAutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield)

> A 64-bit integer, much like an AutoField except that it is guaranteed
>   to fit numbers from 1 to 9223372036854775807.

### Older versions of django

You need to create your model like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then after `./manage.py makemigrations` has been run, open the generated migration and add the following into he operations list:

```
migrations.RunSQL("CREATE SEQUENCE myapp_seq"),
migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE myapp_mymodel ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('myapp_seq')");
```

**Update**

A valid point was raised by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) in the comments. In postgreql the following query works

```
INSERT INTO myapp_mymodel(name) values('some name');
```

but the following doesn't because primary keys are not null

```
INSERT INTO myapp_mymodel(id, name) values(null,'some name');
```

unfortunately it's the second form of the query that's passed through by django. This can still be solved with a bit of work.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id :
       cursor = connection.cursor();
       cursor.execute("SELECT NEXTVAL('myapp_seq')")
       id = cursor.fetchone()
       self.id = id[0]

     Model(MyModel,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't think that code for old versions will work properly; without it being explicitly marked as an autofield Django won't know to get the new id from the database on save.